# A problem caused the program to stop responding and the last name is not printing properly

Tags: c++

Question:

**Write a program that would print the information (name, year of joining, salary, address) of three employees by creating a class named 'Employee'. The output should be as follows:
Name        Year of joining        Address
Robert            1994                64C- WallsStreat
Sam                2000                68D- WallsStreat
John                1999                26B- WallsStreat**

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Employee
{
        char name[10];
        int year;
        char address[20];
public:
    void initialize()
    {
        cout<<"Enter name,year and address"<<endl;
        cin>>name>>year>>address;
    }
       void display();
};
 void Employee:: display()
{

    cout<<name<<"\t"<<year<<"\t"<<address<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    Employee e[3];
    for(i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        e[i].initialize();
    }
     cout<<"Name"<<"\t"<<"Year of Joining"<<"\t"<<"Adress"<<endl;
      for(int j=1;j<4;j++)
    {
        e[j].display();
    }

}
```

The output is:

Enter name,year and address
Robert
1994
64C-Wallstreet
Enter name,year and address
sam
2000
68D-Walstreet
Enter name,year and address
John
1999
26B-Wallstreet
Enter name,year and address

V
C
Enter name,year and address
Enter name,year and address
Name    Year of Joining Adress
V       0       64C-Wallstreet
sam     2000    68D-Walstreet
       1999    26B-Wallstreet

Process returned 255 (0xFF)   execution time : 64.884 s
Press any key to continue.

And a notification pops up saying something stopped this program from running correctly.

Comment: Array indexing starts from 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Note that array indexing in c++ starts from `0`. This means for an array of size `N`, the valid indexes are `0, 1, 2, ..., N-2, N-1`.

So in your example, the loop that goes over the indexes should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        e[i].initialize();
    }
```

and similarly:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        e[j].display();
    }
```